# Python - How to make turtle go to (x,y) position without having it move across the screen?

Tags: python, coordinates, turtle-graphics

I want to know how to make `Turtle` go to an (x, y) coordinate without having it move across the screen. I tried the `.goto()` and `.setposition()` methods, but they both make the turtle move across the screen. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried using [setx](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.setx) and [sety](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.sety)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pen up, then set the turtle invisible, then use goto to move the turtle to your position.

```
turtle.up()
turtle.ht()
turtle.goto(x, y)

# reshow the turtle
turtle.st()
turtle.down()
```

Comment: Just because i could find it in the manpage by searching for the string: `ht = hideturtle(self)`, and `st = showturtle(self)`. same goes for `up = penup` and `down = pendown`.

Comment: This doesn't change the speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable movement animations by setting [`turtle.speed(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.speed). This will make the `Turtle` move instantaneously across the screen.

```
import turtle

turtle.setup(400, 300)  # set up canvas

my_object = turtle.Turtle()  # create object
my_object.speed(0)  # configure object to move without animations
my_object.goto(-150, 0)  # move object

turtle.done()
```

[image: A thin black line originating from the center of the window towards an arrow on the left]

Sources:

- [Python Documentation - turtle.speed()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.speed)
- [Runestone Academy - A Few More turtle Methods and Observations](https://runestone.academy/ns/books/published/thinkcspy/PythonTurtle/AFewMoreturtleMethodsandObservations.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20speed%20up%20or,go%20as%20fast%20as%20possible.)

Answer (score 0):

`.speed(0)` still takes time to move the turtle, and hiding/showing the turtle doesn't change the overall delay.

The only way to move the turtle somewhere instantaneously (in a single frame) is to disable tracer, which is turtle's internal update loop, and use `.update()` to trigger a redraw after repositioning the turtle. You can re-enable tracer if you want after the move.

Here's an example showing 100 gotos performed in a single frame:

```py
from random import randint
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(0)  # disable turtle's update loop
w, h = screen.screensize()
t = Turtle()

for _ in range(100):
    t.goto(randint(-w, w), randint(-h, h))

screen.update()  # draw the frame

screen.tracer(1)  # optionally re-enable the internal update loop
t.goto(randint(-w, w), randint(-h, h))

screen.exitonclick()
```

You can use `t.penup()` to avoid the lines, and you can use `t.hideturtle()` if you don't want to see the turtle.

If you're trying to make a real-time game, animation or app where precise control and user input is necessary, see [this more involved demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70979967/6243352).